# How can I pull iPhone contacts into UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, webview

I'm trying to find a way to import iPhone native contacts onto a UIWebView page. Users should be able to tap a button on the web view to pull up list of phone contacts and then choose some contacts from that list. Once they're done selecting contacts, the UIWebView must show all contacts selected (contact info could be names, phone number, email, etc).

I read about intercepting requests made from UIWebView by using UIWebViewDelegate and it looks promising as far as going from UIWebView to some native view. But how do I bring the data from native view into the UIWebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at using UIWebView's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script` to inject address book data as a JSON string into your webpage.

I think the hardest part for you will be extracting all the address book data into a formatted JSON string.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate? I have used that method before to run simple js functions embedded on my web page which is loaded in the webview. I just pass in my js function name as string @"myJsFunction()". Are you implying it'd work if I pass in formatted NSString* like @"myJsFunction('my json string')"? I'll try that out soon.